# Install-Package : '7.0.4-IR19' is not a valid version string. Error

Tags: nuget, umbraco, nuget-package

I want to add UmbracoCMS nuget with Package Manager Console(Install-Package UmbracoCms). But i can't ...

Attempting to resolve dependency 'Lucene.Net (≥ 2.9.4.1 && < 3.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'SharpZipLib (≥ 0.86.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'MySql.Data (≥ 6.9.8 && < 7.0.0)'.
Install-Package : '7.0.4-IR19' is not a valid version string.
Parameter name: version
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  UmbracoCms
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Try asking on our.umbraco.org if you haven't already. IR could be Internal Release or something, either way it sounds wrong. Or try Install-package UmbracoCms -Version 7.0.4 instead? Latest version is 7.5.8 though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what is causing your problem, but I might have an alternate way of setting things up that could help you. When we nuget our umbraco sites, we only nuget the `UmbracoCms.Core` package. This gives us all the dlls and references we need. It also makes it a lot easier for us to upgrade umbraco. The `UmbracoCms.Core` nuget package is something that you would already get automatically as a dependency by nugetting the whole `UmbracoCms` package.

We then take a zip of the version of umbraco we want and manually merge that into the project using a tool like BeyondCompare. We like to handle the rest of the files outside of nuget because sometimes those other files require special care when merging during an upgrade.